# How do I say there are (number) main points?

Tags: translation

I'm writing an essay on my detailed study for Japanese which is 和食 and I would like to say that there are 4 main points to 和食 but I'm a bit unsure how to translate this...

someone help me please :((((

Answer (score 1):

I think「四つの要点」or 「四つのキーポイント」might be what you're looking for.